# KVM / QEMU - Confused by bridge ip address (on Debian host)

Tags: networking, virtualization, bridge, qemu, linux-kvm

I have followed a few guides to getting a bridge setup on my Debian VM host

The most useful I found to be this:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-bridged-networking-with-libvirt-and-kvm

I have read a series of other guides available online, however they all seem to skip over the details of the IP configuration and don't give any details as to why particular addresses/networks and gateways have been chosen.

For example, in the linked example above, a bridge is created with the address `192.168.0.90`, on the network `192.168.0.X/24`. However no explanation as to why this was the case was given.

I tried following this, creating a bridge myself one the network `192.168.1.X/24`. This took down my network connection to the VM host, which itself is on that network.

My main issue extends from the fact that I don't have a clear picture as to what a bridge actually is or represents. I know it is used to join two different networks together as if they were the same network.

When I tried again to configure my system, I chose to give the bridge a static ip of `192.168.10.1/24`.

This seemed to work and I was able to create a new virtual network which uses the bridge. See screenshot below...

[image: KVM / QEMU bridge network]

I then booted up a VM with this network configuration:

[image: VM network configuration bridge network virt-manager]

And it is able to connect, and obtains the IP `192.168.1.190` from my DHCP server.

Here's where my confusion start and the questions arrive.

- Why did creating a bridge with an IP address on the same network as the `192.168.1.X` network break network connectivity?
- Why does it work when the bridge has a "random" ip address, such as `192.168.10.1`? I don't have a `192.168.10.X` network here, I made that number up.
- If a bridge connects two networks together as if they were the same network, why does it only have one associated ip address? (How does a bridge actually work? I wasn't easily able to find any helpful information about this online.)

By the way, here's a screenshot of the virtualization host `ip a output`: As you can see there are multiple NICs on my VM host. One of which is the regular network connection, the other is associated with the bridge.

[image: KVM / QEMU virtual network vm host network configuration]

---

List of other links

- https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/create-and-run-virtual-machines-virt-manager/
- https://jamielinux.com/docs/libvirt-networking-handbook/bridged-network.html
- https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/VirtualNetworking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that the Linux "br0" interface represents two objects at once:

1. the actual layer-2 bridge, which connects all of its assigned "ports" without any IP processing;
2. and a *bridge port* that allows the host OS to be a member of the same bridge.

For example, when you configure a bridge br0 with two ports eth0 and eth1, in reality it has three: the third one is br0 itself. (You could imagine that the actual "bridge" exists somewhere *behind* br0.)

Similarly, if you have a *managed* 8-port Ethernet switch, it really has 9 ports: one of them connects internally to the management CPU, which allows that switch to be configured through the network. (This is often called the "CPU port".)

> If a bridge connects two networks together as if they were the same network, why does it only have one associated ip address? (How does a bridge actually work? I wasn't easily able to find any helpful information about this online.)

You're thinking of IP routers.

A bridge is very different from a router; it doesn't need *any* IP addresses to function: it works at "layer 2" or the "MAC layer", which means it forwards packets purely based on their Ethernet header (e.g. destination MAC) and doesn't even look at the higher layers such as IP.

The IP address you assign to br0 actually belongs to the host OS – it's how the Linux system itself can participate in the bridged network, in exactly the same way as if configuring an IP address on eth0 that's connected to an Ethernet switch.

(While Linux still lets you assign IP addresses directly to the bridge ports, they usually won't work as expected. Once e.g. eth0 is assigned to be a bridge port, eth0 no longer sends or receives packets by itself – it's under control of the bridge.)

So the *most likely* answer to

> Why did creating a bridge with an IP address on the same network as the 192.168.1.X network break network connectivity?

is that the new address conflicts with your actual Ethernet LAN connection – i.e. you ended up being connected to two networks with identical addresses.

Either a) the OS began trying to reach your physical gateway (192.168.1.1 or .254) through the bridge, but the bridge wasn't (yet?) connected to that physical network, or b) the opposite: the enp6s0 interface *was* made a bridge member, and therefore no longer able to send its own packets, but it still had the IP address assigned and the OS kept trying to send packets through it.

Comment: Ok that makes sense - what is the purpose of assigning an address to the bridge? For a managed switch it is to be able to address the web interface which is presented by a server behind the IP of the managed switch, but in this case, what is the ip address `192.168.10.1` for? What can it be used for? What is it's purpose? It seems meaningless to assign an IP to a device which only looks at ethernet headers and ARP information.

Comment: Like I said, you're not assigning it for bridging, you're assigning it for so that the OS could **act as a host** on the bridged network. So the address can be used for any regular IP communications, really.

Comment: Ok, so if I were to ping that address from some other system, assuming it was able to find a route to that address, I would be pinging the same computer as the one which "manages" the bridge?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: However, presumably in this case, as I picked a "random address" which is not in the same address range as any "nearby" network, I assume it is completely impossible for another machine to route traffic to this address. Since no other machines on the network will know about the `192.168.10.1` machine or even the `192.168.10.X/24` network... because there is no such network... Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: Well, on the one hand, the very act of assigning an IP address from that network **creates** such a network... (Neither a router nor a DHCP server is necessary for a network's existence.) But on the other hand, yes, you're right that hosts in other networks _will not_ automatically know where to reach this address. It would be _possible_ to route traffic to it, but only with manual configuration of the routes involved. (It should be fairly easy in theory. Slightly depends on whether the bridge in question contains purely virtual ports, or whether it also contains physical Ethernet ports.)

Comment: Thanks, that's useful info. Yes, I assume I could setup a static route to this specific address, and this would be one way of doing such a thing.

Comment: More usefully, you would set up a static route to the entire 192.168.10.0/24, and configure VMs to use addresses from that network. This would turn the host into a router between the two networks (the physical LAN eth0 and the virtual machine LAN vmbr0).

Comment: Interesting comment - actually this is what I was deliberatly trying to avoid. I have already been able to set up routed networks with VM's behind them. What I was trying to do was setup a bridged network so that I could have one DHCP server to manage all IP addresses across all of my networks.

In order words I wanted the VMs to be given IP addresses in the same network range as other physical devices on my network.

Comment: In that case, just continue with what you were doing earlier (i.e. setting up your physical Ethernet interface as a bridge member). If you have two physical ethernets and want eno2 to be exclusively for VMs, then put it in the bridge, and don't assign any IP address to the bridge at all.

Comment: Ok, not having an IP address on the bridge seems to make a lot more sense. I will remove the `address` `broadcast` and `netmask` fields from the `/etc/network/interfaces` file